# ZFS data corruption on multiple disks at same time

Tags: zfs

im facing data corruption in my ZFS pool.
I have RAID10 with 1TB Disks.

After few days from pool creation there are 2 checksum errors on 2 disks at once. I also had same problem with RAID1 where appeared some checksum (same count) errors at same time. What can cause this?
I already changed sata cables, switched to new disks, checked bad sectors but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause for multiple disk starting to flake out simultaneously is a failing PSU. Distant second is disk controller. Vibration can also cause this, e.g. a fans with dodgy bearings, but they usually get noisy long before they cause enough vibration to upset HDDs.

Comment: This. I had the same problem one week ago and after replacing the PSU and switching from onboard SATA to a HBA the problem disappeared and my throughput increased.